# Does the Laser Targeting System alert enemies?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

If I have a gun with the laser targeting system equipped, and I shine it in an area where there are unaware enemies, will they become aware of my presence and go into the alerted state?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. Enemies will never react to the laser reticule (even if you're "shining" it right in their eyes).

Comment: Sounds like an awful flaw to me.